# Two instances of AsyncStorage in React Native?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

Can I have two instances of AsynStorage? I get that when you set an item you can for example stringify an array and have something like:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem( 'names' , '[John, Carl, Sam]' );
```

Because I understood that you cant save an Object or an Array as a value in AsyncStorage. So is there a way to have more than one instance to have something like this:

```
Instance 1 AsyncStorage:
-["a","aaa"]
-["b","bbb"]
-["c","ccc"]

Instance 2 AsyncStorage:
-["d","ddd"]
-["e","eee"]
-["f","fff"]
```

And call for example Instance2AsyncStorage.getItem("d") and if I want something from Instance 1 I do Instance1AsyncStorage.getItem("a")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert it to string and save it and then when you want to use it you can parse it. For example:

```
const arr = ["a", "b"];
// First you should convert it to string and then save it
await AsyncStorage.setItem('names' , JSON.stringify(arr));

// Then you can do this for using it:
const response = await AsyncStorage.getItem('names');
const result = JSON.parse(response);
```